# What action should I take when I see an answer to a question that is itself a question?

Tags: discussion, answers

A few times I have seen people answering questions only to say that they are experiencing similar problems to the OP a recent example is Peter's answer to [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8676/connected-to-tor-network-still-not-able-to-browse-the-web).

What action should I take when I see this, for example should I **flag** it for moderator attention, **down vote** it as not useful, or should I just ignore it? Or is this acceptable use of question space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **flag** it as *'Not an answer'*.

> (o) not an answer
>   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.